# How to use AndroidAnnotation @SharedPref with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-annotations, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to use AndroidAnnotations `@SharefPref` within kotlin, but Iget following error

```
org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref can only be used on an element that extends org.androidannotations.api.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesHelper
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
//Interface
@SharedPref(SharedPref.Scope.APPLICATION_DEFAULT)
open interface MyPreferences {
    @DefaultInt(-1)
    fun someIntValue():Int
}

//Fragment
@Pref
lateinit open var sharedPref:CongressPreferences_

//usage within fragment
val get: Int = sharedPref.selectedEventId().get()
```

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory? `MyPreferences` does not extend `SharedPreferencesHelper`.

Comment: @azizbekian No it's not. Working with `Kotlin` and `Annotations` sometimes throws errors, which are not related to the real issue. This happens if the annotated code gets generated. (see solution below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16006) in the Kotlin annotation processor.
To fix this, [you must add](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15421#comment=27-1907540) `correctErrorTypes = true` to your `kapt` block.

```
kapt {
  correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

Also make sure you are using the latest Kotlin version (as of this moment: 1.1.3).

Comment: I found the fixed bug report at android annotations, but it didn't told about adding `correctErrorTypes` ( https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/334 ) Thanks!

Comment: You found the wrong issue, it was reported in 2012. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna extend on @WonderCsabo 's answer.
His answer almost saved me, but not fully.

After adding this to my app label build gradle.

`kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }`

I wasn't able to run my app.

> Then I closed my android studio and then run Android studio again as administrator.
>    Voila! it works like charm.

Thank you @WonderCsabo